# Adding css to an element after clicking on actionButton

Tags: shiny, shiny-server

i'm trying to customize a login page with shiny. I have include a textInput like this `textInput("login_username", "Username")` and what i want to do is when the `Username` is not on the database then `output$login_username` 's borders will turn red. So how can I add CSS to an element after an event.

Let's say this is my `if` sentence :

```
if(is_validate){ /* action to do */ }
else { output$login_username <- /* action that i'm looking for */ }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres small example how to add the colors with the help of `shinyjs` package, I've also added a notification on bottom right with a message:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

allowedusers <- c("Pork_Chop","BKenz")
jsCode <- "shinyjs.TextCol = function(params){$('#login_username').css('background', params);}"

# For border color use below
jsCode <- "shinyjs.TextCol = function(params){$('#login_username').css('border-color', params);}"

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  extendShinyjs(text = jsCode),
  textInput("login_username", "Username"),
  actionButton("Login","Login")
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  observeEvent(input$Login,{
    req(input$login_username!="")

    if(!(input$login_username %in% allowedusers)){
      js$TextCol("red")
      showNotification("user doesnt exists",type="warning")
    }
    else{
      js$TextCol("white")
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

[image]